# how to unblock Thunderbird in China ?

Tags: thunderbird, email, firewall

China has recently blocked all email clients from sending mail. I use Thunderbird for a pop3 account. When I try to send mails, they are blocked and I receive a message stating my mail is spam. If I use the same pop3 account via the state-approved browser site, the mail will go. The block problem occurs for all email clients in the Ubuntu repository [Evolution, Claws, Sylpheed]. I am told Outlook has no such problems. Obviously, China has cut a deal with MS for back doors.

Might anybody know how to work around this to enable T-bird to send emails ?

Comment: What is your email domain (@xyz.com) and smtp server name?

Comment: @vleague.com.cn      smtp.mxhichina.com

Comment: Set up a VPN to a less restrictive country?

Comment: @saidakkas: after much research, China seems to use the smtp to detect non-approved email clients and thus block the outgoing emails.

Comment: If you ping your smtp server, is this the IP you get? 205.204.101.152

Comment: "PING smtp.mxhichina.com (42.120.219.29) 56(84) bytes of data."
"64 bytes from smtp.mxhichina.com (42.120.219.29): icmp_seq=1 ttl=40 time=6.70 ms"

Comment: @rob , that IP doesn't belong to your smtp server unfortunately. Original IP I mentioned is your actual smtp server in US, IP reported is 42.120.219.29 from China. If China interferes with DNS servers, your only option is VPN service from outside China. Safe to say, when you send via 'official' channels, they will intercept your emails with no difficulty.

Comment: so, I need to use a vpn service and configure T-bird to use the 205... address for outgoing mails?

Comment: @saidakkas:  could you please tell me how I can, by myself in future, determine the true IP ?  many thanks.

Comment: @robgrune, assuming the state is interfering with DNS (you get different IP resolution in China than rest of the world), healthier way would be to use one of the online tools (i.e http://mxtoolbox.com/NetworkTools.aspx )to get `A record` of smtp server address. You can try using 205.204.101.152 in Thunderbird without connecting to any VPN. If you are using VPN to tunnel your internet connection to outside China, you don't need to configure anything different for Thunderbird.

Comment: @saidakkas. bingo! configuring tbird to use the 205... as the smtp IP seems to work with no vpn- emails are now going out to various parties. many thanks!  I shall try the mxtoolbox site and see what I can learn from it.

Comment: @robgrune, glad it works. One point though, if IP address is used instead of FQDN address, encrypted smtp setup will give certificate check fails. I'm assuming you are sending without encryption. Your ISP or anyone else who can sniff the traffic can get the entire content of your outgoing emails.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/43114/discussion-between-saidakkas-and-rob-grune).

Comment: [BlockedInChina.net](http://blockedinchina.net) may also be of use for you

Answer (score 2):

As per [our discussion](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/43114/discussion-between-saidakkas-and-rob-grune) with @robgrune , his DNS lookups for smtp server is pointing to a different IP address than what global DNS records show.

Finding the correct `A record` via [mxtoolbox](http://mxtoolbox.com/NetworkTools.aspx) for the smtp server and replacing the smtp address with this IP address fixed the issue **as a workaround**.

However this will cause 'certificate validation errors' if smtp settings include use of encryption. Ideal solution would be to use VPN, then certificate validation failures would not happen and user could be sure that his/her traffic is not intercepted by anyone.

Answer (score 0):

"Recently"?

I think that wasn't "Golden Shield Project" that block your e-mail client. Maybe was your e-mail account server that was update, in the server POP3 or IMAP. Try to delete your account of the app and use the automatic function of thunderbird to add the account again. I had the same problem some times ago and I live in Brazil.

Don't forget save the inbox and update your system before to do anything.